# Stretch paragraph to containing div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to manage to stretch the **paragraph** to it's parent **div**. Normally I thought this worked with `width:100%` and `height:100%`, and making it `display:inline`. But I'm probably missing something here. I did a Google search for my question (copy paste the title) and no result.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QuantumHive/D8rUa/

Comment: you want 3 paragraph to fill the div area horizontally or vertically or something else???

Comment: yes, the paragraph should have the same height and width as it's first parent div.

Comment: Why would my question be downrated?

Comment: So like this? [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/D8rUa/7/)

Comment: Ruddy's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: **BANG** and the dirt is gone! Glad I could help @QuantumHive

Comment: @Ruddy : If you could post you answer I can mark that as THE answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets see what we have here:

### HTML:

```
<div id="bday">
    <div id="day">
        <p class="value">16</p>
    </div>
    <div id="month">
        <p class="value">december</p>
    </div>
    <div id="year">
        <p class="value">1989</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#bday {
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#bday div {
    height:10%;
    border:inherit;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 0px 0px 3px;
    position:relative;
}
#day {
    width:15%;
}
#month {
    width:45%;
}
#year {
    width:25%;
}
.value {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

We need to get the `<p>` to `display: block;` and give it a `height` + `width`. Also take away the `margin` or it will flow out.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/D8rUa/7/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your answer:

```
.value {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

Remove all other properties from `.value` and put these 2 only.

Comment: That's not entirely the correct answer, there is still a little part in the div that's not filled: http://jsfiddle.net/QuantumHive/D8rUa/11/

Comment: sorry, didn't tried in fiddle. now it should

Comment: That works too, but I marked Ruddy's answer as the correct one since he was the first one that commented the correct answer in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If i can understand it must be like: http://jsfiddle.net/D8rUa/2/

```
#bday {
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
#bday div {
    height:100%;
    border:inherit;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:3px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 3px;
    position:relative;
}
#day {
    width:15%;
}
#month {
    width:45%;
}
#year {
    width:25%;
}
.value {
    display:inline;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: @ quantum : is this your answer

Comment: No. You are stretching the child div! I'm talking about the paragraph element. The height in #bday div should stay 10%.

Comment: @QuantumHive : when height is `10%`, what good will stretching the `p` would do??it will not be visible...will it??

Comment: @NoobEditor : There are two kind of divs. The most outer div has the id="bday". And this div has child divs. Those child div's have a height of 10%. These child div's have paragraphs as children. They should have the same height as these divs that have height 10%.

Comment: @QuantumHive : posted the answer....please chk!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is clearfix. You need to put this piece of code in and add clearfix to your classname.

http://davidwalsh.name/css-clear-fix

Answer (score 0):

add

```
p.value {
    display:inline-block; /*ammended*/
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-bottom:1000px;/*optional */
    margin-bottom:-1000px; /*optional */
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8rUa/9/)

if you remove `padding-left:3px;` in `#bday div`, the left gap would disappear too!!

Comment: I guess that kinda works, but still prefer Ruddy's en Era's answers.